# Is there a way to define the fraction of each label I want in sci-kit learn cross validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I've written a simple Python script that uses `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` and `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV` to make predictions about binary classification data, each point being labelled either 0 or 1. In the training data, roughly 90% have the label 1 and 10% have the label 0. In the test data, roughly 35% have the label 1 and 65% have the label 0. This proportion is known, although the labels aren't known.

My model is currently over-fitting. My cross-validation score for the training data is 85-90%, but the score when I run the code on the test set is below 40%.

One workaround I've thought of is that I could try setting `GridSearchCV` to split the data so that each training/validation set has approximately the same proportion of labels as the test data. This doesn't seem to be an option with this library however, and my google-fu hasn't returned any results in terms of other sci-kit learn programmes.

Are there any other libraries I could use, or a parameter I could input that I haven't managed to find? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the [`imblearn`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-imblearn.over_sampling) library, as it offers a great variety of methods for re-sampling. I do not know the size or other specifics of your data set, but in general, I would argue that oversampling strategies should be favored over undersampling ones. You could for example use [`SMOTE`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html#imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE) to oversample your 0 labels in the training set.  The `sampling_strategy`  parameter also allows you to specify your desired ratio beforehand.

Comment: This seems to answer my question perfectly, thank you.